# c++: sqlite callback function does not print to screen

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback

using `sqlite3` C++ bindings with `GCC(MINGW) 4.6.2`

the following code does not work i.e the callback function does not print anything to the screen.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

using namespace std;

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    for (int i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        cout << azColName[i] << "=" << argv[i] << endl;
        cout << "\n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


class db
{ 
public:
    sqlite3* mydb;
    char database;
    char* mysql;
    char* zErrMsg;

    db()
    {
        zErrMsg = 0;
    }



    void open(string mydatabase)
    {
        sqlite3_open(mydatabase.c_str(), &mydb);
    }

    void exec(char* mysql)
    {
        int rc = sqlite3_exec(mydb, mysql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    }

    void close()
    {
        sqlite3_close(mydb);
    }
};


int main()
{
    db* mystorage;
    string s_var = "test.db";
    char* sql = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY;";

    mystorage -> open(s_var);
    mystorage -> exec(sql);
    mystorage -> close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the result of sqlite3_open.  If it is non-zero, it didn't work.  Also, you have a class variable and a parameter in exec with the same name.

Comment: @cup with the code above, I do not get any compiler or run time errors, the code just does not execute during run-time. So i removed SQLITE3_EXEC and checked the output for only SQLITE3_OPEN and the same thing happens i.e. no compiler or run time errors but just does not execute

Comment: @cup Also I changed the name of the parameter in exec but that did not help.

Comment: It is not a compiler error - C++ allows that.  I'm asking you to check the result of sqlite3_open.  Are you getting a non-zero result?  You can find out the reason with sqlite3_errmsg.

Comment: Another problem is that you haven't made an instance of db in main.  You are just using the pointer without initializing it.

Comment: @cup wow that is embarrassing! yes it works now, I had a blank pointer, did not realize that, thanks!